# TypeError: selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not function

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am a beginner in automation testing and I am doing one udemy course named: "Selenium Webdriver with PYTHON from Scratch + Frameworks". In this course, framework development section, when I tried to separate code for each web page in OOP manner, I got mentioned error although I checked my code it looks correct. For this project, I am using python 3.11 , selenium 4.9.1 and pytest 7.3.1. I run my code in pycharm editor.

My code for CheckoutPage.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class CheckoutPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    cardTitles = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card h-100']/div/h4/a")
    cardFooter = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-footer button")
    checkoutButton = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "nav-link btn btn-primary")

    def getcardTitles(self):
        return self.driver.find_elements(*CheckoutPage.cardTitles)

    def getcardFooter(self):
        return self.driver.find_elements(*CheckoutPage.cardFooter)

    def checkoutButton(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*CheckoutPage.checkoutButton)
```

My code for test_e2e.py

```
import time

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from pageObjects.CheckoutPage import CheckoutPage
from pageObjects.ConfirmPage import ConfirmPage
from pageObjects.HomePage import HomePage
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass


class TestOne(BaseClass):
    def test_e2e(self):
        homePage = HomePage(self.driver)
        homePage.shopItems().click()

        checkoutPage = CheckoutPage(self.driver)
        elements = checkoutPage.getcardTitles()
        confirmPage = ConfirmPage(self.driver)
        i = -1
        for ele in elements:
            i = i + 1
            if ele.text == "Blackberry":
                checkoutPage.getcardFooter()[i].click()
        # self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class*='btn-primary']").click()
        checkoutPage.checkoutButton().click()
        time.sleep(5)
        # self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='btn btn-success']").click()
        confirmPage.checkoutConfirm().click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "country").send_keys("Bangla")
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='suggestions'] ul li a")))
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='suggestions'] ul li a").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@for='checkbox2']").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Purchase']").click()
        success = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible']").text
        assert "Success! Thank you!" in success
```

The error occurred in CheckoutPage.py line no 19 although a similar method worked well in lines 13 & 16.

The error I got in the [command prompt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UAa_7sMuPAx6ogrLju7UIbrUiQjRbJK3/view?usp=drive_link) screenshot.

Comment: Please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), especially the long traceback at the end. It is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have a method named checkoutButton and a class-level variable with the same name.

```
def checkoutButton(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*CheckoutPage.checkoutButton)
```

This causes a conflict and leads to the error. You should rename either the method or the class-level variable to resolve the issue.
To fix the error, you can rename the method checkoutButton to something else, such as getCheckoutButton.

```
checkoutButtonLocator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "nav-link btn btn-primary")
def getCheckoutButton(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*CheckoutPage.checkoutButtonLocator)
```